# BalanceOf always returns 0

Tags: solidity, javascript, dapp-development, ethers.js, binance-smart-chain

I am trying to get the WBNB balance for an address by executing the following:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const secrets = require('./secrets.json');

const WBNB = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"; // WBNB contract

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(secrets.provider);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(secrets.privateKey);
const signer = wallet.connect(provider);

const WBNBContract = new ethers.Contract(
    WBNB,
    [
        'function approve(address guy, uint wad) public returns (bool)',
        {"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},
        {"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},
        {"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}
    ],
    signer
)
async function main() {
    const address = "0xf1F5f818387Fbf9F087AF7f6c1d0E487ba522D0d";
    const balance = (await WBNBContract.balanceOf(address)).toString();
    const symbol = await WBNBContract.symbol();
    const dec = await WBNBContract.decimals();
    console.log(balance);
    console.log(dec);
    console.log(symbol);
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
0
18
WBNB
```

However, when I go to the [WBNB contract page on BscScan](https://bscscan.com/address/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c#readContract) -> Contract -> Read Contract and enter the exact same address in the balanceOf() function, I get the proper balance which is  40000000000000000.
Wallet page with WBNB in it: https://bscscan.com/address/0xf1f5f818387fbf9f087af7f6c1d0e487ba522d0d

I am trying to get the balance because of another issue, which is that my transaction always failed (insufficient funds for gas * price + value), so I guess this explains why it failed (because reported balance is always 0).

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to BSC mainnet and not BSC testnet? Also, for running transactions you don't need WBNB balance, but account balance, which you can check using `address(_address).balance`.

Comment: How can I make sure that I am connecting to Mainnet? In this example I am using ankr to get the JsonRpcProvider, and the WBNB contract address is the one from mainnet as well).
At this point I would like to understand why exactly I am not getting the expected results from balanceOf call, so that I understand all of this better (especially because I do get proper results on BscScan and I wonder what do I do wrong).

Comment: I fixed it, apparently the JsonRPCProvider that I got from ANKR (binance-smart-chain API) was the issue. I changed the provider to:
https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/ and it gives proper results now.

Comment: Is there any reason why I would prefer to use ankr JsonRpc endpoint instead of the one recommended by binance?